# javascript regex in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Okay, a little context. I want to modify some crappy HTML on a page that I use a lot. I'm doing this via my content_script "js", as defined in the manifest.json file of the chrome extension. The primary method I've been using is this sort of ugly thing:

```
var str1 = 'something already on the page';
var str2 = 'something already on the page, plus some extra stuff';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(str,st2);
```

I'm mostly trying to re-order form objects, and expand them a little to show more information, and filter/condense them to be less superfluous. I'd appreciate any pointer as to a better way to do this.

Anyway... here's my specific problem.

I want to retrieve `pistol` (or any string) from the following:

```
<form action="map.cgi?use-o" method="post" class="a"><input type="submit" value="pistol" class="m"\></form>
```

I tried every variation of the following:

```
str.exec(/value="([^]+)" class/);
```

and I'm either getting `null` or junk strings that I don't want. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using regex, why not use html dom functions

Comment: You are better off to use JavaScript code for it

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on regex, then use below one:

```
(?:value=")([^"]+)
```

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gO3vM8/1)

Using JavaScript it will look like:

```
var value = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].value;
```

Comment: does this just look for the string `"input[type=submit]"` or is it more intelligent than that somehow? also, are you missing an open parenthesis?

Comment: It takes the first input submit on the page. I can not see your whole page, but it will work for provided code.